# AWS uploading a photo to s3 bucket using Node.js

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-cli

I am having trouble uploading a photo to my s3 bucket. I believe it to be a credentials error. I can upload a photo using aws cli but cant upload using this node.js code (I get a timeout):

```
var config = require('./config.json');
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({region:config.awsRegion});
var s3 = new AWS.S3();
var fs = require('fs');



 module.exports.upload = function(fileName, cb){
   var bitmap = fs.readFileSync('./photos/'+fileName);

   var params = {
     Body: bitmap,
     Bucket: config.s3Bucket,
     Key: fileName
    };
    s3.putObject(params, function(err, data) {
      fs.exists('./photos/'+fileName, function(exists) {
        if(exists) {

          fs.unlink('./photos/'+fileName);
        }
        });

      if (err) {
        console.log(err, err.stack);
        cb(err);
      }else{
        //console.log(data);
        cb(null,data);           // successful response
      }

    });
}
```

Anybody have any clue?

Here is the main server code:

```
const express    = require('express');        // call express
const app        = express();                 // define our app using express
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const basicAuth = require('express-basic-auth');
const Raspistill = require('node-raspistill').Raspistill;
const camera = new Raspistill({
    width: 600,
    height: 600,
    time:1
});


const s3upload = require('./upload-s3');
const speaker = require('./speaker');
const faceSearch = require('./search-faces');


app.use(basicAuth({
    users: { 'raspi': 'secret' }
}))

// configure app to use bodyParser()
// this will let us get the data from a POST
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

var port = process.env.PORT || 80;        // set our port

// ROUTES FOR OUR API
// =============================================================================
var router = express.Router();              // get an instance of the express Router

// test route to make sure everything is working (accessed at GET http://localhost:8080/api)
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.json({ message: 'hooray! welcome to our api!' });
});
router.post('/capture', function(req, res) {
  var fileName = new Date().getTime()+".jpg";
  console.log('filename', fileName);
  camera.takePhoto(fileName).then((photo) => {
    console.log('photo captured');
    //speaker.speak('Image has been captured... ');
    s3upload.upload(fileName, function(err,data){
        if(err){
          res.json({ status: 'fail' });
        }else{
          console.log('uploaded image to s3 bucket: '+fileName);
          //speaker.speak('Image has been uploaded to S3 bucket raspi118528');
          faceSearch.search(fileName, function(err, data){


            if(!err){

              if(data.FaceMatches && data.FaceMatches.length>0){

                  //var text = 'Hello '+data.FaceMatches[0].Face.ExternalImageId + '. How are you?';
                  var text = data.FaceMatches[0].Face.ExternalImageId ;
                  // text += Number.parseFloat(data.FaceMatches[0].Similarity).toFixed(2)+' % confident that you are '+
                  // data.FaceMatches[0].Face.ExternalImageId;
                  //speaker.speak(text);
                  res.json({ status: 'matched', key: fileName ,message: text});

              }else{
                  res.json({ status: 'unmatched', key: fileName ,message: "Hello! We never met before. What's your name?"});
                  //speaker.speak("Hello! We never met before. What's your name?");
              }
            }else{

              //speaker.speak("I can's see any faces. Are you human?");
                res.json({ status: 'error', key: fileName ,message: "I can's see any face. Please come in front of camera?"});
            }
          })

        }
    })
  });

});
// more routes for our API will happen here

// REGISTER OUR ROUTES -------------------------------
// all of our routes will be prefixed with /api
app.use('/api', router);

// START THE SERVER
// =============================================================================
app.listen(port);
console.log('Magic happens on port ' + port);
```

Again, I am able to upload a photo using aws s3 cp cat.jpg s3://raspberrypijohnypie/ --region us-east-1

However there must be something wrong with my credentials. This is because after my server snaps the picture and stores it in the photos folder, it is unable to upload it.

Comment: Your tags indicate aws-lambda but I don't see any Lambda code. Is this Lambda? Credential issues wouldn't yield a timeout typically. Are you running this in Lambda in a VPC (without a route to the internet)?

Comment: sorry I just thought I needed to have more tags. This is part of the server that gets called by my lambda. I have no issue running the lambda. Ill add some more information to my OP

Comment: I simply needed to update my aws credentials as sudo user

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems ok but you are not explicitly passing any credentials. It is OK if you are running it in an EC2 instance or a Lambda function with a role attached or if you are running your code locally but have environment variables that includes your credentials set. Not having them would not result in a time out, instead the putObject function would return with a 403 error.

I suggest that you comment out the part where you check and delete the file and see if the execution at least get to that point, and if so what error it is throwing (once the file does not end up in your bucket I assume an error is happening).

If you want to try and test with explicitly passing your credentials then you should instantiate your S3 client like this

```
var s3 = new AWS.S3({
    apiVersion: '2006-03-01',
    accessKeyId: '',
    secretAccessKey: ''
});
```

**Another (unrelated) point is** that deleting your photo before checking for errors is dangerous. If any error happens you will loose it forever. You should move deletion logic after error checking.

Comment: hmm... now my "Hello" intent isn't working. Thanks for the thorough reply! I should mention this is not my code. I am following a tutorial from a very helpful person named Mithun: https://github.com/just4give/raspi-dexter-lambda

Comment: I think you need to specify the region also at some points in order to intanciate the s3 / aws sdk ...

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you will require to pass credentials. It is always better to allow the code to read credentials from the aws credentials file. So the steps would be:
 1. Create .aws folder in your home directory.
 2. Navigate inside and create a file by the name 'credentials'
 3. Put in a '[default]' at the top and then add your region and both access-keys on lines one below the other.
 4. In your code, read it like this:

```
const credentials = new AWS.SharedIniFileCredentials({profile: 'default'});  
AWS.config.credentials = credentials;
```

After the above line, you can initialize your S3 object and try doing CRUD operations.

P.S.: Since you can use aws-cli, you should already have .aws folder setup!